# Does the Airfoil Tools Cd/Alpha Curve include both induced and parasite drag?

Tags: drag, airfoil

I'm looking at Cd / Alpha for the SD7062 Profile:

http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=sd7062-il

Wondering if it includes both induced and parasite drag. How does one tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question you have to look at the source:

[image]

[Induced drag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27885/8749) is a drag type which appears on wings with finite span. The polars given are for a 2D profile section and therefore without induced drag.

What about the parasitic drag? Using Wikipedia's [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_drag) only skin friction and form drag are taken into account. Interference drag, which is a 3D drag type dependent on the position of other bodies, can't be included either.

Comment: That makes absolute sense! Thank you! My next questions was how to calculate drag taking aspect ratio into account, which the typical drag formula doesn't take into account.

Comment: In https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/induced.html there is a formula for the induced drag. If it doesn't answer your question post a new one explaining what do you want to know.

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right track @mns. My more detailed question is now here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35176/how-do-you-calculate-total-drag-on-a-wing